# Factoring $p^3x-pc^2x^{-1}+c(1-p^4)=0$ to $(x-cp)(p^3x+c)=0$ without trial and error

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, conic-sections, factoring

I was doing a AS Further Pure Past Paper from 2018 from the Edexcel spec. For question 5, which was about rectangular hyperbola, I needed to factorize this:
$$
p^{3}x - pc^{2}x^{-1}+c(1-p^{4})=0 \tag1
$$
in order to find the value of $x$ in terms of $p$ and $c$. I know that the answer is:
$$
(x-cp)(p^{3}x+c)=0 \tag2
$$
but I don't know how to reach that answer without trial and error.

I was hoping that someone could outline a method to solve for $x$.

Comment: That factored expression has an $x^2$ term and it does not have a term in $\frac 1x$.

Comment: The initial expression is essentially quadratic in $x$ (just clear the denominator by multuiplying by $x$).

Comment: $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$p^3x-pc^2x^{-1}+c(1-p^4)=0$

$\implies x^{-1} (p^3x^2 - pc^2 + cx - cp^4x) = 0$

$\implies (p^3x^2 - pc^2 + cx - cp^4x) = 0$

$\implies ((p^3x^2 + cx) - (pc^2 + cp^4x)) = 0$

$\implies (x(p^3x + c) - pc(c + p^3x + c)) = 0$

$\implies (x - cp)(p^3x + c) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

since the normal meets the curve at $(cp,\frac{c}{p})$, $(x-cp)$ must be a factor

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that? I am used to a "normal line" being perpendicular to a tangent line, but which variables are you using for horizontal and vertical on the graph?  And why would the normal line intersecting the curve somewhere else be relevant for factoring?

Comment: The equation of the normal was constructed from the point $(cp,c/p)$ in the first place. The other factor indicates the $x$ coordinate of where this normal meets the curve again

Comment: Okay, that didn't really answer my question at all, but I'll take a stab at it myself. $x$ is the horizontal, $y = f(x) = p^3x-pc^2x^-1 + c(1-p^4)$.  I have no idea where you got the point $(cp, c/p)$ from.

Comment: those are the parametric coordinates